# TextArea not clickable in IE6

Tags: html, internet-explorer, internet-explorer-6

I have a simple textarea which works in all browsers i.e. I can click inside it and type.

But I can't do this with IE6! I am however, able to press the tab key until I get to the textarea and then I can type in it. But I cannot click it.

What a strange quirk? Anyone know what the hell is going on?!

The source of my form can been found [**here**](http://pastebin.com/bU3b5Lqd).

Thanks all for any help

### Update

[**Here**](http://pastebin.com/4UTT8X9j) is the CSS. Nothing jumps out at me.

### Update 2

Annoying, I have narrowed down the problem to this line:

```
background-image:url(../../images/checkout_fuzzy.png);
```

I use this setup for all my sites pages, but this is the first page that has text areas in it so I guess that might be the reason why it doesn't like the above. What possible could I change the above to so that it doesn't overlay the textarea.

### Solved

A `position:relative` on the containing div solved my IE6 problem! The problem was that the text area was not clickable due to something (div) covering the textareas as identified by Chris.

Comment: can you add the class stylesheeet for it?

Comment: The html you attached is working, It's probably a CSS problem.

Comment: I have attached the CSS.

Comment: Although the HTML doesn't validate, I can confirm that all the textarea fields can be clicked in when loaded in my copy of IE6.

Comment: About ‘Update 2’: that CSS rule is for `#box`, which isn't shown in the HTML excerpt you provided. Can you show the full page (including the Doctype declaration)?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I don't know what's going on but I have some thoughts that may or may not be the problem. I would hazard a guess that it might be stylesheet related. Its possible in HTML to have something invisible in front of a form element that stops it receiving a click but I would think that wouldn't stop the input getting tabbed to.

To test if this is the case see if you get the same problem if you don't reference your stylesheet at all. If this allows you to click its something to do with your CSS/layout. If you still can't click then I'd probably try turning javascript off on your browser and seeing what difference that makes...

The HTML looks totally fine to me at a glance but I of course can't see what your CSS and/or javascript might be doing on the page. Best of luck. :)

Comment: I have attached my CSS. I think you are right something is covering it as when I try to select other bits of the page it works but not the text near the teatarea! Looks like the form itself?!

Comment: @Abs – What happens when you simply comment the CSS inclusion out, so there are no stylesheets applied to your form?

Comment: @Marcel - it works when I remove the css. I have narrowed down the problem to a line in the CSS file. See update2.

Answer (score 0):

Not 100% sure if this will fix it, but try setting the 'cols' attribute in the textarea.

Here's an example.

```
<textarea rows="2" cols="20"></textarea>
```

IE6 can be a bit fidgety if it doesn't get what it expects.

Comment: Yeh, I tried that already, it didnt work. I also had single quotes and I changed them to double quotes it didnt work!

Answer (score 0):

I don't have a copy of ie6 handy but I do know that ie6 can get real funky with absolute and relative positioning. try commenting out your absolutely and relatively positioned CSS styles and see if any of them are covering your form.